# Git clone fails for private repository using Terminal

Tags: git, github, terminal, repository

I am trying to clone a private repository using the Terminal, but it fails stating the following errors:

1. The repository does not exist.
2. Failure connecting with credentials.

I can successfully clone the same repo using xCode & Source Tree. I've added & verified SSH key & tried HTTP & SSH but the clone fails in both cases.

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you post your errors when trying to clone the repo in the terminal ?

Comment: With ssh you can also set verbose option:
    `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone example`

Comment: @RannLifshitz this is the error message. ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @ErniBrown debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok, a little more step: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone example`

Let it be more verbose

Comment: Can you make connection to the github.com via ssh? Ssh complaints about missing public key.

Comment: @ErniBrown It shows a lot of information, I don't know which one to pase here

Comment: @JanMarek I tried using SSH, it shows this.... ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Comment: Can you edit your OP and clearly display the terminal commands you are using and their outputs?

Comment: @Zubair `ssh` complaints, that it cannot find a public ssh key, which is the main problem. But I don't know, where you can find this key. In Linux, it is in the ~/.ssh directory...

Comment: @JanMarek debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey

Comment: @JanMarek debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:s0KDlBlFPDea2mzL+ZIKfChqh+S0RaWImCOITQXPyXA /Users/macUser/.ssh/emmacUser-GitHub
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([19X.XX.XXX.XXX]:XX).

Comment: @Zubair Ah, I see, it was my fault, sorry. Are you sure, that the whole URL to the repository is right?

Comment: @JanMarek yes, I'm sure, used same url in source tree and everything works fine, issue occurs when I try through Terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many attempts I've found the solution. When you have to clone a private directory, git clone command changes a bit.
Usually what we do is

```
git clone https://github.com/zzzubair/TestGit.git
```

which is fine if TestGit is public repository. But for private repository you've to mention your user name, which has right access to clone the repository, so this command changes to this.

```
git clone https://zzzubair@github.com/zzzubair/TestGit.git
```

I hope this'll help many others who are or will face the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using github and windows, verify that you generate your personal access tokens ([more info here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/)) and select the **"repo"** option (Full control of private repositories). Else, your token will be useful for public repositories.

Comment: I'm using mac & solve the using by adding user name in git clone url.